# How copy some object from big array into small array but not all.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am wondering whether I can copy a certain amount of objects but not all from an array to another array. For example: bigArray has 10 objects, i just want to copy 4 objects from it into smallArray. Please help me out. Thanks a lot

```
NSMutableArray *smallArray = [bigArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: do they have to be random objects? or just the first 4?

Answer (score 4):

Use the following method...

```
- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range
```

As per Apple docs...

> Returns a new array containing the receiving array’s elements that fall within the limits specified by a given range.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
NSMutableArray *smalllArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[bigArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which objects you want to include in your sub-array you can either make the new array as a subset containing a specific range of the big array or you can base the sub array on certain criteria by making a search predicate.

For the contiguous range, use:

```
- (NSArray *)subarrayWithRange:(NSRange)range
```

For a more sophisticated selection, use:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
```